# I have a manually classified .tfrecord's but can't figure out how to train a model, any tips?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I can code in many languages so don't really care about the implementation but just looking for some simple/concise tutorial on how to get a trained model out of my tfrecords.

Comment: Does you question mean you have data in tfrecord format and you want to train model using that?

Comment: In addition to [this guide from the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord), there are plenty of tutorials around about this, e.g. [this](https://medium.com/mostly-ai/c46bc4bbb564) and [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/36d111b3ff4d) from the top of Google. If you have a specific question with some of that, or something that is not working, please post a concrete question about that.